# MYSQL search fields method

Tags: mysql, database, search

Please help, I'm very confused about my situation.

I'm beginning to create a search function but I'm not sure the best way to go about it.
On the front-end users will be able to enter words in a text-field, then these will search the MYSQL database, something like below:

[image]

so they search for 'Adult' and every item_id (Primary Key) with 'Adult' in column 'name' is listed. Or they enter 'black' and every item_id with 'black' in 'colors' is listed. or they enter 'Adult Blue' and *every* item with either 'Adult' *or* Blue would come up. I'm sure you get the idea.

I've read up on multiple methods, but I can't figure out which is best:

Using a **MANY TO ONE** table: This seems like it would work, but there are over 500 unique items, so that would be thousands and thousands of rows. For item_id 1 I would have to make a row for 'Adult', a row for 'Denim', a row for 'Pants', a row for 'black', a row for 'red', a row for 'blue'. I might as well just hard code everything.

Using `FIND_IN_SET`: Is this going to work? Would I have to store the values with commas like `Adult,Denim,Pants` and also `EXPLODE` to separate the values? I was going to try this method but I keep reading that storing multiple values in a field is very bad practice.

Or are **Regular Expressions** what I'm looking for?

What is the best way to store the values, and what is the best way to retrieve them? I'm not asking for exact code, just the methods to use. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to look into FullText indexing?

Comment: I don't know what this is, I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if we suppose that columns `name` and `colors` are the only columns we need to search through, I'd do the following (naive solution but will work fine if your DB doesn't have millions of rows and you don't have thousands of customers searching at once).

First, create a view

```
CREATE VIEW SearchHere AS
SELECT item_id, CONCAT(name, ' ', colors) AS FullDescription
FROM table
```

I don't know the name of the table in your screenshot, so I used `table` as its name.

Now, if a user searches for `adult red pants` you could issue a query

```
SELECT item_id
FROM SearchHere
WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%adult%'
AND FullDescription LIKE '%red%'
AND FullDescription LIKE '%pants%'
```

Of course, you'd need to generate the query on the fly but that's not an issue. You could play with using `AND` or `OR` and placing spaces in between the wildcrad symbol `%` and the search term. Probably you would also want to do the view in a more sophisticated way, e.g., do more tha just `CONCAT`.

Comment: so I would have to take the search query the user puts in and turn that into a variable right? So the real query would be something like

`SELECT item_id
FROM SearchHere
WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%variable01%'
AND FullDescription LIKE '%variable02%'
AND FullDescription LIKE '%variable03%'`

Comment: @user2118228 yes. You receive user's search query, split it by whitespaces and construct an SQL query in a cycle, iterating through the list of query words. But I suggest you also take a look at full text search capabilities of MySQL as suggested.

Comment: I'm going to do a mix of this and full text search. Thanks for your seuggestion, the %value% was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution is to use

```
name REGEXP 'the|search|terms'
OR colors REGEXP 'the|search|terms'
```

You should explain what you mean by best, though -- fastest performance?  easiest to maintain?  other?