# live searching multiple database fields using linq

Tags: c#, database, linq, livesearch

I'm basically looking for a 'google type' search of my database.

I'm currently creating a application which stores books (and authors), Games Movies (and more in the future). The application, obviously, also needs to be able to quickly search the database for any of these items.

Of course simply splitting up the games, books and movie searches is no problem, though I would really find it awesome if I had 1 search field for everything, mainly because I sometimes confuse books with movies xD

Now at first I thought this would be a nice way to go about it (simply only searching for books):

```
List<Book> books = (from b in le.Book
                    where (b.Title + " " + b.Author.FirstName + " " +
                    b.Author.Surname).Contains(search)
                    select b).OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToList();
```

This is easy, and works fine with a small database and when you type the search in the right order.
so using this a search would look like:

```
The fault in our stars John Green
```

but if someone were to type:

```
John Green The fault in our stars
The fault in our stars - John Green
```

or what ever variation you can come up with, it would fail.

I did find quite a nice example for a SQL query here: [MYSQL search fields method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361676/mysql-search-fields-method) but it's in SQL and I do not know how to re-write this to linq. Because the database (is going to) contain thousands of records, so I can't just do:

```
var total = (from b in le.Book
             select new { b.ID, FullDescription = (b.Title + " " +
             b.Author.FirstName + " " + b.Author.Surname) });
string[] searchArr = search.split(' ');
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
foreach(string s in searchArr)
{
    ids.addRange((from t in total
                  where t.FullDescription.Contains(s).ToList());
}
```

The foreach loop would slow it down too much (I know there must be a better way to create a variable number of where statements but I don't know how to do that either).

But yeh the `var total` would become huge.

Then of course there is the part of making it a live search so it updates the list view every time a character is typed so if I type: `"jo"` I would get a list with results, then I can define it further by typing `"joh"` but would it be better to query the List of results I got from the last query or to re-query the whole database?

Also I need to take into account the Backspace, so if someone typed `"jo"` but wanted `"ja"` I need to re-query the entire database anyway right?

So what is the best practice for doing this? I've found quite some examples like the one mentioned but I'm searching for the fastest and "user proof" (meaning no matter how strange  the search it still needs to come up with the right result)

My database model (only containing books, authors)

[image: The model of my database]

P.S. I am not the best database designer so if you find something you would do different let me know (still got a lot to learn)

Comment: This subject is so vast, there where quite a few books and academic publication written. You might want to review the subject of Full Text Search http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search

Comment: Hmm, well I did not realize it would be that difficult xD
any ideas on how to get the simple version (like the link to the mysql search fields method) to work with linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking an incredibly deep question, and I don't think there is a "right" answer but I do think there are "good" and "bad" approaches given your requirements and assumptions.

Fundamentally you are trying to accomplish the following:

1. Given a particular query string, you want to determine an ordering on your data row `R`
2. This ordering should be deterministic
3. This ordering should be easy to calculate
4. This ordering should reflect similarity or relevance between your search string and the members of `R`

You must first accept that unless we define the problem better, this is more of an art than a science. "Relevance" here is not well-defined. However, we can make some common-sense assumptions about what might be relevant. For instance, we might say that a relevant result has these qualities:

1. The search string is included in the members of `R`
2. More members of `R` with the search string indicates a more relevant result
3. Certain members of `R` are more important than others
4. We should allow for typos/mistakes - ie, a partial match is worth something

Then we can determine a "score" for `R` row as follows:

1. Each member of `R` gets a "weight" with a minimum value of `1` and no maximum value
2. The score for `R` is equal to the sum of the weight of each member divided by the "distance" between the member and the query string
3. The distance is defined in terms of a well-known string distance metric like Levenshetin or SoundEx

For instance, if your `R` has members `Name`, `Description`, and `URL`, you might weight these `100`, `10`, and `1`, respectively, and apply the Levenshtein metric.

This is not even close to the tip of the iceberg, for it would be such a poor algorithm that it would be useless. Better approaches include cross-referencing members of your data row, looking up members against known dictionaries, and developing an evidence-based model for scoring results.

But scoring is a valid way to reduce the problem into an easier-to-state one.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bit to take in.

oke, so i knew this was going to be difficult but i will take a look into the algorithms you named, i take great pleasure in deep and difficult questions and algorithms so i have the feeling this will be fun, thanks for your answer and i'll keep updating my post with progress.